# Apache Reverse Proxy with a subdirectory in domain using Docker

Tags: linux, wordpress, docker, apache, reverse-proxy

I'm using Docker inside a dedicated server with CloudLinux and I'm trying to set up a WordPress inside the container. The problem is that when entering the URL: https://domain:8088/subfolder, it redirects me to https://domain:8088.

I have configured within the following route:

/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/{user}/{domain}/

The app.conf file where the following reverse proxy settings.

**app.conf**

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

#Redirect requests to /subfolder to the subfolder container on port 8088
ProxyPass /subfolder http://domain:8088/
ProxyPassReverse /subfolder http://domain:8088/

<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

#Redirect traffic from http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{domain}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:php8.2-apache
    container_name: aqmunwp
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    volumes:
      - {URL}:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - mysql:mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.13
    container_name: aqmunwpdb
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db_data:
```

I already managed to make the reverse proxy work, if I enter the domain/subfolder url it redirects me to wp-admin/install but with the port, that is, domain:8088/wp-admin/install. Do you know how it can be hidden?

**Edit: app.conf**

```
ServerName domain

     ProxyPass /dir/ http://domain:8088/
     ProxyPassReverse /dir/ http://domain:8088/

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
     RewriteRule ^/dir(/.*)?$ https://domain/dir$1 [R=301,L]
```